# Shiny-server installation: Server not responding on port 3838

Tags: r, apache, ubuntu, shiny-server

I installed the shiny-server on a Ubuntu 16.04.1 and according to the console output it is active and running:

```
    systemctl status shiny-server
● shiny-server.service - ShinyServer
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/shiny-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-08-24 18:17:09 CEST; 15h ago
  Process: 13175 ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 13179 (shiny-server)
    Tasks: 7
   Memory: 28.5M
      CPU: 158ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/shiny-server.service
           ├─13174 /bin/bash -c /opt/shiny-server/bin/shiny-server --pidfile=/var/run/shiny-server.p
           └─13179 /opt/shiny-server/ext/node/bin/shiny-server /opt/shiny-server/lib/main.js --pidfi
lines 1-11/11 (END)
```

Then I opened the port 3838 as stated in the installation guide:

```
netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3838            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -

sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
3838/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3838/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Howevever if I try to access my server over the port 3838 in a browser, I don't get any response from the server and the site stays blank and eventually times out.

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there was some problem with the port 3838 on my server. Although the console output above states that it is open and listed as "LISTEN", it still didn't work. When I changed the default port for my shiny-server in the configuration file (/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf) to 80, it suddently worked:

```
    # Define a top-level server which will listen on a port
    server {
       # Instruct this server to listen on port 3838
       listen 80;
       ...
```